# Combining data based on column in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have data in following format in hive table.

```
user |  purchase | time_of_purchase
```

I want to get data in

```
user | list of purchases ordered by time
```

How do I do this in pyspark or hiveQL?

I have tried using collect_list in hive but it does not retain the order correctly by timestamp.

Edit : 
Adding sample data as asked by KartikKannapur.
Here is a sample data

```
94438fef-c503-4326-9562-230e78796f16 | Bread | Jul 7 20:48
94438fef-c503-4326-9562-230e78796f16 | Shaving Cream | July 10 14:20
a0dcbb3b-d1dd-43aa-91d7-e92f48cee0ad | Milk | July 7 3:48
a0dcbb3b-d1dd-43aa-91d7-e92f48cee0ad | Bread | July 7 3:49
a0dcbb3b-d1dd-43aa-91d7-e92f48cee0ad | Lotion | July 7 15:30
```

The output I want is

```
94438fef-c503-4326-9562-230e78796f16 | Bread , Shaving Cream
a0dcbb3b-d1dd-43aa-91d7-e92f48cee0ad | Milk , Bread , Lotion
```

Comment: In Spark < 2.0 it is practically impossible with DataFrames alone.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with additional libraries or any sort of conversion to RDD etc.

Comment: You can alway convert to RDD and groupByKey with all performance penalties.

Comment: You should be able to use Spark SQL to do the same. If you need some more help, post a sample of the data you are working with.

Comment: @KartikKannapur I'm curious, how would you do that with DataFrames alone? `collect_*` supports only primitives (< 2.0.0) , individual aggregations are scheduled separately in (> 1.6.0) so you can reason about the order, there is no `Dataset` support in PySpark and every other approach requires cumbersome tricks with moving data to and from  Python which is equivalent to using RDDs. Not to mention it is yet another group by key :)

Comment: @KartikKannapur I have posted a sample of the data , can you check if it can be done in sql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is

First create a hive context and read table to a RDD.

```
from pyspark import HiveContext
purchaseList = HiveContext(sc).sql('from purchaseList select *')
```

Then process the RDD

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
purchaseList = purchaseList.map(lambda x:(x[0],[x[1],dt.strptime(x[2],"%b %d %H:%M")]))
purchaseByUser = purchaseList.groupByKey()
purchaseByUser = purchaseByUser.map(lambda x:(x[0],[y[0] for y in sorted(x[1], key=lambda z:z[1])]))
print(purchaseByUser.take(2))
```

Output

```
[('94438fef-c503-4326-9562-230e78796f16', ['Bread', 'Shaving Cream']), ('a0dcbb3b-d1dd-43aa-91d7-e92f48cee0ad', ['Milk', 'Bread', 'Lotion'])]
```

Save the RDD as new hive table

```
schema_rdd = HiveContext(sc).inferSchema(purchaseByUser)
schema_rdd.saveAsTable('purchaseByUser')
```

For reading and writing hive table see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412954/reading-and-writing-from-hive-tables-with-spark-after-aggregation) and [spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)